# Is it possible to deploy a heroku war app with Java 1.7?

Tags: heroku

I tried updating system.properties to say 1.7, but it seems to stay at 1.6.

When I deploy via maven, system.properties works.

When I deploy via:
heroku deploy:war --war

it reverts back to 1.6 ignoring my system.properties. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering whether perhaps deploying with "heroku deploy:war" doesn't pick up the system.properties file. Try deploying by pushing your Git repo instead.

Comment: the problem i'm running into is that i have a shared jar. which git does the code go into . . .

i'm using a war, so i can deploy everything as one big happy package. also, i'm thinking since google uses war too, i can easily try both platforms . . .

Comment: oh, btw as a temporary workaround, i'm trying to do this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies

it really sucks, because now i have custom scripts copying things all over the place, and have to run a mvn deploy each time i update my shared library. that causes another version in my local repository, and it seems to be cached in heroku's local maven cache. i wonder if that counts against my slug size. anyways, totally new to maven, but learned way too much about it today. sucks